# Adding color to margins in CSS

Tags: css

I'm using this code to center/position a fixed width image as my background. I need to add color around the image that fills the margins in the browser window. I've tried background color, border color...

So, the width of the image is 1050px. If the browser window is 1500px I want to make the remaining area black (for instance). How can I do this?

```css
#content {
    text-align: left;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 825px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(file:///X|/CarFingers/tabback1_hor.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<body>

</body>
</div>
```

Comment: Give the body a background-color?

Comment: Wait what? You can't put `<body>` inside a `<div>`...

Comment: @TheZ the image can have transparency.

Comment: Not going to solve your problem, but I don't think you can have `body` tag inside of a `div`.

Comment: @TylerCrompton Hmmm, then I'd nest the image in _another_ container (or simply have it beneath the image somehow) and have that background-color:white. That way the body background can still be black or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you should not have a `div` tag enclosing the `body` tag. If you put the `div` within the `body` you should be able to simply set the background color of the `body`.

Answer (score 7):

First: put the `div` INSIDE your `body`. Then you can just edit your body background like this:

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: solved. I knew it was something easy. Seeing cross-eyed here. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamSmith - Please accept this answer if you think it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to know how to color a border in CSS it would be

```css
border: 10x solid #000;
```

or

```css
border-width: 10px;
border-color: #000;
border-style: solid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#content {
    text-align: left;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 825px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('file:///X|/CarFingers/tabback1_hor.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;      /* Add this to your code */
}
```

In your html you should do something like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="content">
   </div>
</body>
```

You should never enclose the BODY in DIV